# Gallery child count

Tags: android, java, gallery

Есть галерея с миниатюрками картинок. При создании активити мне нужно поменять фон первых двух миниатюр на экране.

Проблема в том, что getChildCount() возвращает 1 для этого состояния. Всего отображено, к примеру 9-10 миниатюр.

Какой юзкейс тут применить?

**UPD**
Впринципе, я зря заморачивался с чайлдами.
Все просто и решение ниже. В адаптере, getView():

```
if( conf.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
    if( position == 0 || position == 1){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));   
    }
}
else {
    if( position == 0 ){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));   
    }
}
```

ибо, в методе подсветки все равно делаю так:

```
public void highlightSelectedThumbs(Gallery bigPages, Gallery thumbPages){
        ...

    for(int i = 0; i < thumbPages.getChildCount(); i++) {
        thumbPages.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Comment: статический фон сделай для первых 2х

Answer (score 1):

Надо делать рекурсию по чайлдам, скорее всего картинки обернуты сверху `ViewGroup`, который вы видите. Возьмите от него еще `getChildCount()`

Comment: ViewGroup vgr = (ViewGroup)thumbPages.getChildAt(0);
              if( vgr.getChildCount() > 1 ){
               LogUtil.log("vgr.getChildCount() > 1");
               vgr.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
               vgr.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
              }

Не помогло. Или я не так вас понял?